# List item navigation not working on Safari/Chrome in iOS on iPhone/ iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I'm creating a webpage with navigation in an unordered list.

On an iPhone, or iPad, I click the link and nothing happens. I 'touch' the link, only for the background colour to change and nothing happen. The only way to get the link to activate is holding the link in for a couple of seconds for default iOS options to appear, i.e. 'open in a new window'. There are other links and navigation on the site which work correctly. It's just this one set of links that's causing me trouble.

Can you see anything in the HTML or CSS which may cause this?

Is this anything to do with fading transitions applied to the list item?

See the markup at the bottom. (I've removed a few things like text/background styling classes as it's probably irrelevant to the problem.)

---

*HTML*

```
<ul class="list">           
    <li>
    <a class="example" href="#">
    <i class="icon-medium icon-map"></i>
    <p><strong>Example description goes here</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="example" href="#">
    <i class="icon-medium icon-map"></i>
    <p><strong>Example description goes here</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

*CSS*

```
.list ul { list-style-type:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
.list ul li { display:block; float:left; width:50%; min-height:100px; position:relative;  transition: .2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out; }
.list ul li a.example { display:block; width:100%; height:100px; }
.list ul li:hover, .list ul li:active { color:#FFF; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may be causing you some problems are your  tags. They are deprecated italics tags and shouldn't hold any class attributes(except of rare occasions). Try removing these or changing them to the proper tag(not sure what you are going for there). That may fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jpm61704 - I'm just using the <i> class method as used in the likes of bootstrap. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: I'll give your method a go though! Thanks.